# Disabled labels doesn't gray out

Tags: vb.net, label, tablelayoutpanel

I have a form with a label control and a tablelayoutpanel. There's a label in tablelayoutpanel too. All controls are disabled by default so when the form is loaded both labes are grayed out.

Controls are enabled at runtime, when the labels switch to black.

But when the controls are disabled again, then the label inside tablelayoutpanel doesn't gray out.

I've tried tablelayoutpanel.refresh and application.doevents but the disabled label still stays black.

I want both disabled labels gray. Any suggestions? There should not be a need for changing the forecolor of the label.

Comment: After you disable the label, loop through all the controls on your panel and confirm their enabled value. Maybe you're not hitting the correct control or something else is re-enabling them.

Comment: Please spend some time in the Help Center and learn how to write an appropriate question.  Pay particular attention to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).